# Implementing keyboard shortcuts in .NET2.0 windows application

Tags: windows, .net-2.0, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any framework available for implementing keyboard shortcuts in a .NET2.0 windows application? Also what are the best practices which should be taken care of while doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there's no obvious way to provide accelerator keys for commands not in menus, it's not very hard to add these. There are five basic steps:

*Define an accelerator enumeration.*

```
private enum Accelerators { Unspecified = 0, Home, Save, Print, Logout };
```

*Create a hash table to contain the enumerated values.*

```
Hashtable _accelHash() =  new Hashtable();
```

*Create a class to represent accelerator keys.*

*Load the table with the Keys enumeration.*

```
_accelHash.Add(new AcceleratorKey(Keys.Alt|Keys.H),
                                  Accelerators.Home);
_accelHash.Add(new AcceleratorKey(Keys.Alt|Keys.S),
                                  Accelerators.Save);
_accelHash.Add(new AcceleratorKey(Keys.Alt|Keys.P),
                                  Accelerators.Print);
_accelHash.Add(new AcceleratorKey(Keys.Alt|Keys.X),
                                  Accelerators.Logout);
```

*Finally, override ProcessCmdKey and use a switch statement to dispatch to the right method.*

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg,
                                      Keys keyData)
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, for a slightly more sophisticated approach, you could have the hashtable map to delegates which were the methods you wanted to invoke, as long as they all had the same method signature.

[Here's a short article](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4639) that outlines the steps above in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of implementing shortcut keys is to detect them in a keyboard event such as KeyDown or KeyUp.

Example

```
public void Form1_KeyUp(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Control && e.KeyData==Keys.A)
{
//handle ctrl+a
}
```